# Why did Dolores do this to Bernard at the series ending?

Tags: plot-explanation, westworld-tv

At the end of Westworld's second season, Dolores has escaped in Charlotte's body to Arnold's mansion. From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Passenger_(Westworld)):

> Dolores reactivates [Bernard], cautioning him that while they may be enemies, they need each other to ensure the survival of the hosts in the human world.

Why are they both needed for the survival of hosts?

Comment: This is a classic trope : The Villain need a hero. (mostly because if there is no Hero to counteract the villain, the story tends to be short).

Answer (score 5):

### Because she's realised there may be more than one way to survive

Lisa Joy (co-creator/showrunner) explained at the [**Hollywood Reporter**](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/westworld-season-2-finale-explained-lisa-joy-season-3-1122744)

> She's changed her mind. She's changed her philosophy. She realizes she has but one path to potentially securing the hosts' safety, when she helps see through Maeve and Akecheta's plan by securing the sovereignty and safety of the Sublime, to which many of the hosts have escaped.
>
> It's an acknowledgment that there are paths other than hers that she needs to be tolerant and accepting of and can't stand in the way of. It's much like how she tells Bernard that she understands they will likely be at odds. They will likely come into conflict. They may even kill each other.
>
> **But she's come to understand that true freedom isn't something that arises from a lack of dissent, from a dictatorial or totalitarian rule of one set of ideologies. It's something that has to happen with a plurality of ideas, sometimes coming into conflict.**
>
> Because she's learned her lesson, she's bringing Bernard back into this world to be a check on her own power, in some ways

Comment: There was also this line she says earlier too in response to Bernard  questioning her actions at The Forge. She says, "You don't understand anything." . So even though the EPs view Ford as an "underwriter", I still think there is massive sway/power there (ie: Ashley Stubbs-Charlotte scene) and still had control, and therefore I kind of feel like she switched "modes" in that moment, but obviously going with what LJ says here, she did lose her cornerstone and I think the separation of cornerstones is how one would test the supposition, presented in the this episode, if the hosts can change.